# OnBackPressed for Fragment is not setting home fragment name (Default fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

In app there are six fragment,just for example
6. AboutUs (6th fragment Name)
1. MainFragment (1st fragment Name)

whenever I back pressed from 6 fragment.I directly go to first fragment but the name in ActionBar contain 6th fragment name with MainFragment under action bar.I want to change it but not getting a way

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    backCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    System.out.println("back count " + backCount);


    if (backCount == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        builder.setTitle("Warning");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.show();
    } else if (backCount == 1) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        setTitle("Laundry");

    } else if (backCount > 1) {

        for (int i = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i >= 1; i--) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
            System.out.println("back count loop" + fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
        setTitle("Laundry");
        //fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()=0;
       /* Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new Home_Fragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");*/

    }
}
```

So how can I change name in action bar on back pressed.I am providing screen shot of output.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Rl7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);` instead of  `setTitle("Laundry");`

May it help you !

Comment: @A.Tale save the title as string when you passing the intent

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```